# Configurable product doesn't show simple product images

Tags: configurable-product, magento2.2.2, gallery

After updating to Magento 2.2

Configurable product only shows images assigned to its' own gallery but nothing of the simple products associated with it.

Even when I choose a product via swatch the image doesn't change.

Swatch attribute settings are correct, and has worked in previous version of Magento 2.1

Comment: Please provide more details Or check console log for it.

Comment: That is the biggest problem, there are no errors and nothing in console.

Comment: Please share website URL. Also check magento log and images file permission.